# Java Class cannot override method in abstract class which has a method signature that contains an interface

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I have the setup:

```
public abstract class AbstractDbManager {
    
    
    public abstract boolean createTable();
    
    public abstract int insert(Stockable rm);
    
    public abstract Stockable get(String key);
    
    public abstract int save(Stockable rm);
    
}

public interface Stockable {
    
}


public class Stock implements Stockable{
    
}


public class StockDbManager extends AbstractDbManager{

    @Override
    public boolean createTable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int insert(Stock stk) {
     return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Stock get(String key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int save(Stock stk) {
        return 0;
    }
    
  
}
```

Why wont the methods: `int insert(Stock stk)` and  `int save(Stock stk)`  in `StockDbManager` override the methods:

`abstract int insert(Stockable rm);` and `abstract int save(Stockable rm);` in `AbstractDbManager` despite the fact that every `Stock` is also a `Stockable` ?

Note however that  `Stock get(String key)` method in `StockDbManager` successfully overrides the `abstract Stockable get(String key);` method in `AbstractDbManager`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `insert(Stockable)` requires that it accepts **all** implementations of `Stockable`, and your implementation does not satisfy that requirement of the contract: it only accepts a specific implementation of `Stockable` (ie `Stock`).

For return values this works different: `Stockable get(..)` says it will return a `Stockable`, and given `Stock` is a `Stockable`, narrowing it down in the implementation to `Stock get(..)` is acceptable as it fulfills the contract.

Comment: thanks for answering. I daresay the only way to make it work while accepting only a specific implementation of Stockable would be to use the instanceof operator alongside casts within the insert and the save method right? Or would there be a more idiomatic way?

Comment: @gbenroscience Throwing an exception (or doing nothing) when the implementation is not `Stock` would be a rather poor implementation of the contract of the interface, and would be an indication something is not right in your design. To me it would suggest that either you need to change your interface to use `Stock` instead of `Stockable`, or you need something to convert other implementations of `Stockable` to `Stock` when saving.